# MySQL many to many relationship matching

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database, associative-table

I'm making a cocktail database, and right now I have three tables:

- drinks has columns drinks_id and drinks_name
- ingredients has columns ingredients_id and ingredients_name
- The third is a simple relationship table called recipes that has drinks_id and ingredients_id

I want to query the database with a set of ingredient_ids and get the set of drinks available from that set of ingredients. For example, if drink A contains ingredients (1,2), drink B contains (1,3), and drink C contains (1,2,3), inputting ingredients 1,2 and 3 should return drinks A, B and C. I just started teaching myself database design with MySQL and any help is much appreciated. Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, I tried but didn't quite know how to search for it.

Comment: your example data is too simplistic. Should a recipe with ingredients (1,4) get returned when you put it (1,2,3)? what if you input (1,3) should you return (1,2,3) too?

Comment: To answer your questions, no. Sorry for the ambiguous language, I believe I got at the question better [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686665/query-relation-table-against-another-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRY

```
SELECT d.drink_name
FROM tbl_drink d
INNER JOIN tbl_receipe r ON r.drink_id=d.drink_id
INNER JOIN tbl_ingredient i ON i.ingredient_id = r.ingredient_id
WHERE `given ID` IN (i.ingredient_id)
```

Comment: I would, but I'm such a noob I don't have the reputation.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from drink d where
  exists (select * from recipe where drink_id = d.drink_id and ingred_id = ?) and
  exists (select * from recipe where drink_id = d.drink_id and ingred_id = ?) and
  [...]
```

Bind `?`'s and add an `exists` for each ingredient in the set.

Comment: This answers my question exactly as asked, thank you! Unfortunately I realized that's not exactly what I want. I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT d.drinks_name
FROM drinks d
JOIN recipes AS r ON (r.drinks_id = d.drinks_id)
JOIN ingredients AS i1 ON (i1.ingredients_id = r.ingredients_id)
JOIN ingredients AS i2 ON (i2.ingredients_id = r.ingredients_id)
...
JOIN ingredients AS iN ON (iN.ingredients_id = r.ingredients_id)
WHERE
    i1.ingredients_name = ${first_ingredient}
    i2.ingredients_name = ${second_ingredient}
    ...
    iN.ingredients_name = ${Nth_ingredient}
```

Comment: This answer looks good, but I couldn't get it to work when I tried it. Perhaps because I'm unfamiliar with the ${xxx} syntax?

Comment: The ${xxx} syntax is just place holders for your actual ingredients.

Comment: This requires that you know how many ingredients you want to compare in advance. if n = 3 you can't do 4 ingredients. and you can't do 2 ingredients either unless you put the second on both ${second_ingredient} and ${third_ingredient}

Comment: @Stephanie Page: No, it doesn't require that you know anything in advance. It only requires that you build your SQL statement dynamically. If you _must_ use a statement prepared ahead of time, you can add some `OR ${nth_ingredient} IS NULL` checks, but that will be less efficient.