# query relation table against another column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, entities and components, each with a name and unique ID. There is a third table mapping the many-to-many relationship between these two IDs called construction, containing the two columns, entity_ID and component_ID. An entity is composed of some number of components. So if the construction table looks like this:

```
+----------+---------------+
|entity_id |  component_id |
+----------+---------------+
|        1 |             1 | 
|        1 |             2 | 
|        2 |             2 | 
|        2 |             6 | 
+----------+---------------+
```

Entity 1 is made out of components 1,2, while entity 2 is made out of 2 and 6. The application I'm working on also has an available table containing the IDs of all available components. My question is this, how do I query the database to return the entities constructed strictly of components in the available table? In the given example, if 1,2 and 6 are all in the available table, then entities 1 and 2 should be returned. Otherwise, if 2 isn't in the available table (but 1 and 6 are) then nothing is returned. I'm new to MySQL so if you could explain the logic as well that would be great.

Comment: If you enforce referential integrity, you shouldn't even be able to have an entity with non-existent components. If you do, check for null values and discard those.

Comment: the components table changes frequently. If a component isn't in the table it means that it's temporarily unavailable, not that it doesn't exist.

Comment: How do you know what components are available? Is it a flag on the component table IS_IN_STOCK or do you want to pass that list to the query?

Comment: There's an application that takes user input and fills in the 1-column table that used to be components (now renamed 'available') with the relevant IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested @Abdullah's subquery and indeed got the opposite of what I wanted. After a little testing I ended up with the nested queries that give me what I was looking for:

```
select distinct entity_id from construction 
where entity_id not in (
    select entity_id from construction c left outer join available a on a.id = c.component_id 
    where a.id is null 
);
```

Comment: wait? Where is the many-many mapping table you mention in the question and why is the component_ID on the entity table at all? You're completely confused about third normal form.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this but you can give it a shot.

```
select * from construction c
where not exists (
    select * from construction c2 left outer join available a on a.id = c2.component_id
    where c2.entity_id = c.entity_id and a.id is null
)
```

In the not exists section I'm basically selecting all the entities E that when you join E with its components return at least one null component.

**UPDATE**

To troubleshoot, see if the inner query gives you what you expect:

```
select * from construction c2 left outer join available a on a.id = c2.component_id
where a.id is null
```

Comment: I tried this and it just returned the entire table! Any other ideas?

Comment: try replacing the `join` with a `left outer join`

Comment: Thank you, although I couldn't get your query to work, the subquery helped immensely!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.entity_id, e.name                  --- Show all entities
FROM entity AS e
WHERE NOT EXISTS                            --- for which there not exists
      ( SELECT *                            --- any component that
        FROM construction AS c              --- they need for the construction
        WHERE c.entity_id = e.entity_id     
          AND c.component_id NOT IN         --- and it's not 
                ( SELECT component_id
                  FROM available            --- available
                )
      )
```

Explanation: Show all entities for which there not exists any component that they need and it's not available.